# CSS hiding bottom part of layout when Keyboard is triggered

Tags: android, html, css

i have a webapp i'm trying to make responsive and i'm running into a problem on my Android 5.2 phone where when i click the input, it shows the keyboard and the form gets pushed down i think, leaving this ugly white area at the bottom whenever the keyboard is shown.

I'm using 100vh on the element that contains the background image, could that be what's causing the problem?

I'll link an image of the issue below taken from my mobile phone.
Has anyone run into this issue before? how did you fix it?

[image: Issue Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use this for small screen devices :

```
  body{
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Comment: no nothing, i'm guessing that it's because of the 100vh, the part where it breaks is precisely where the above-the-fold section ends on my phone.

Comment: Then use 100% instead of 100 vh

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake, you must shouldn't use vh for heights, just let the content define the height and if necessary define min-heights, vh messes it up on Mobile whenever you scroll down.